# Shell variables expansion in text file preserving whitespace (e.g. docker-compose.yml usage in Rancher)

Tags: shell, docker-compose, yaml, rancher, variable-expansion

I'd like to perform shell expansion with default values in YAML file preserving its structure and leading whitespace, so to keep it usable.

For example:

```
version: 2

services:
    postgres: 
       image: ${POSTGRESQL_IMAGE:-my-private-registry/postgres}:${POSTGRESQL_BUILD:-9.6}"
       labels:
           io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: myproject=true

    myapp:
       image: ${APP_IMAGE:-my-private-registry/myapp}:${APP_BUILD:-latest}
       depends_on:
           - postgres
...
```

Output should be like:

```
version: 2

services:
    postgres: 
       image: my-private-registry/postgres:9.6
       labels:
           io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: myproject=true

    myapp:
       image: my-private-registry/myapp:latest
       depends_on:
           - postgres
...
```

I'd like to get renderes docker-compose file so I can pass it to Rancher which supports only `version 2` without shell expansion.

What's the best and reliable solution for it?

I tried:

- `envsubst` but it can perform only primitive substitiutions
- shell `eval` but it removes leading whitespace and corrupts file

Answer (score 1):

Finally I came into solution with `eval` preserving space:

```
while IFS= read -r; do eval echo "\"""${REPLY}""\""; done < docker-compose.yml
```

Explanation:

- `IFS=` sets no separator for `read` command so it tries not to split the string (optional)
- `read -r` preserves backslashes in file
- `read` called without variable name puts the whole string without whitespace trimming into the default variable `REPLY`
- `echo "\"""${REPLY}""\""` renders variable and keeps required number of double quotes around it to make string properly printable

UPDATE:

Also it's quite useful to change `version`:

```
while read -r; do eval echo "\"""${REPLY}""\""; done < docker-compose.yml \
   | awk 'NR==1 && ($0~"version:") {print "version: 2"}  NR!=1 {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks easier to me to do the variables expansion in your shell script (instead of *while*) and then replace the .yml with sed (using simpler keywords to do the replacement)

Comment: Thank you for the opinion. I've thought about it, but it looks for me to complex when you need some transformation of them, fox example default values. This way I want to be able use the file directly on localhost with `docker-compose ...` and remotely with `make ...` and another variables.